# JavaScript Remoting for Apex Controllers

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting

please explain what is the difference between these two methods?
I found this in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_namespaces.htm?search_text=You%20can%20use%20the%20$RemoteAction):

> - You can use the $RemoteAction global to automatically resolve the
>            correct namespace, if any, for your remote action.
> - Configuration details for the invocation, if any.

Example:

```
<apex:page controller="TestCtrl">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.staticjs}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function sayHello3(helloTo) {
        TouchCR.TestCtrl.sayHello1(helloTo, function(result, event){
            if(event.status) {
                document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = result;
            }
        });
    }

    function sayHello4(helloTo) {        
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.TestCtrl.sayHello2}',
            helloTo,
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {
                    document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = result;
                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
    }
    </script>

    <button onclick="sayHello1('John');">direct js@staticres</button><br/>
    <div id="result1">[Results]</div>
    <button onclick="sayHello2('Mike');">remotemanager js@staticres</button><br/>
    <div id="result2">[Results]</div>
    <button onclick="sayHello3('Jane');">direct js@onpage</button><br/>
    <div id="result3">[Results]</div>
    <button onclick="sayHello4('Jane');">remotemanager js@onpage</button><br/>
    <div id="result4">[Results]</div>
</apex:page>
```

UPDATE:

> - $RemoteAction can not be used from a Static Resource.

in updated example

- tested on packaging org (namespace prefix enabled)
- methods sayHello1 and sayHello2 placed in Static Resource.

method sayHello2 which is uses $RemoteAction and placed in Static Resource fails.

[image: console.log]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that in the first example the class name was added directly:

```
TestCtrl.sayHello...
```

And in the second example the `$RemoteAction` expression was used.

Why? Suppose you have an org with a namespace (package org or whatever). In that case in order to invoke a remote method you will have to add the *namespace prefix* to the class name: `PREFIX.TestCtrl.sayHello(helloTo, ...` The disadvantage of this method is that it will not work on the other org with a different namespace prefix. Using `$RemoteAction` the prefix will be resolved and  added automatically!

> Use $RemoteAction in an expression to automatically resolve the
>   namespace

Comment: You mean RemoteAction right not RemoveAction?

Comment: @javanoob LOL yeah :)

Comment: @SergeyUtko Any difference in these two methods when using with third party JS libraries, like AngularJs etc?

Comment: @DenisPereverzev There is no difference. Both functions are the same except for for namespace prefix.